# How to switch between frames using selenium library with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, jsp, selenium-webdriver, frames

I trying to switch frame "top" to "body". I tried different ways but I couldn't do it. There is too much source but any of them not working. What is the problem with it? [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrslT.jpg) structure is in the link. Page is "jsp".

```
# 1 
driver.switch_to_frame("body")

# 2
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"/html/frameset/frame[3]")))
```

Maybe the problem is visibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to default content from frame "top" and then switch to "body".

`driver.switch_to_default_content()`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in question, your trying to switch directly from one frame to another frame, which are on same level in DOM like:

```
<iframe name="top"></iframe>
<iframe name="body"></iframe>
```

You need to switch to `defaultContent` before switching to another frame using:

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Then try to switch to frame `body`

```
driver.switch_to_frame("body")
```

We can not directly switch from one frame to another unless targeted frame is located within current frame.

**Ex:**

```
<iframe name="top">
    <iframe name="body"></iframe>
</iframe>
```

Then, we can use:

```
driver.switch_to_frame("top")
driver.switch_to_frame("body")
```

Comment: That was a perfect explanation. I did not know. Thank you, sir. @Kuldeep Kamune